# Jekyll build stuck in "Rebuilding index…" stage

Tags: shell, server, jekyll

I've just built my first Jekyll website, and (almost) everything was going fine, until I added a few (around 80) old posts from my previous website.

Now, when I try to run Jekyll to serve the website locally, it starts, but stay stuck in the `Rebuilding index…` stage:

```
$ ./_serve.sh
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      posix-spawn (~> 0.3.6)
      listen (~> 2.7)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Configuration file: _config.yml
Configuration file: _config-twitter.yml
            Source: /Users/nhoizey/Dropbox/Personnel/Devs/nicolas-hoizey.com
       Destination: /Users/nhoizey/Dropbox/Personnel/Devs/nicolas-hoizey.com/_site
      Generating... 

  Populating LSI... 
Rebuilding index...
```

The `_serve.sh` I run here is just this:

```
#!/bin/sh
jekyll s --config _config.yml,_config-twitter.yml
```

(`_config-twitter.yml` contains only my Twitter API credentials I don't want to share)

The whole site source and content is in my Github repo: https://github.com/nhoizey/nicolas-hoizey.com/

Google didn't help at all, nor did Stackoverflow yet, any idea?

Comment: I still have this problem. I cannot build the Jekyll site locally, only with it running on Travis-CI. There should be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across this issue myself, but [found a better solution](http://footle.org/2014/11/06/speeding-up-jekylls-lsi/).

Installing gsi and using the rb-gsl gem *significantly* speeds up LSI for me (~6sec)

Comment: `rb-gsl` is now `gsl`, but it is really really faster indeed! Thanks A LOT, I should have seen your answer way earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your site and everything seems to be running find when : 
 - disabling twitter tags :p
 - disabling LSI in _config.yml

While the site is building I Ctrl-C to see what was running, and I get the following stack :

```
Rebuilding index... ^C/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/matrix.rb:315:in `[]': Interrupt
    from /Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/matrix.rb:823:in `block (3 levels) in *'
    …
    from /Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/classifier-reborn-2.0.3/lib/classifier-reborn/extensions/vector.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in SV_decomp'
    …
    from /Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

I finally found [this issue](https://github.com/jekyll/classifier-reborn/issues/14) on Github on the plugin gems-classifier that is used to generate relative links with LSI.

I guess your best option is to disable LSI…